# googleapis npm module documentation

Tags: node.js, npm, documentation, google-oauth

I am coding server side with expressjs and needing to have access Gmail API through OAuth 2.0

I followed this [guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) and stumbled upon this statement `new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);`

I couldn't find the documentation regarding `google.auth.OAuth2` constructor/function on internet, can someone direct me to the official documentation ?

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client

Comment: And https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: @AkshendraPratap Could you please point out where I can find `google.auth.OAuth2` function signature, what parameters are required ?